# python obtener el mayor precio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hola saludos a toda la comunidad stackoverflow, estoy trabajando con python necesito de su gran ayuda a un problemita, me estoy consumiendo unas apis, pero al momento de querer obtener el valor mas alto tengo problema pero al solicitar el menor no si me lo muestra bien, voy a dejar parte de mi codigo y la salida del mismo

```
precioads=None
if (precioads is None or  float(x['price_formula_value']) > float(precioads)):
    precioads=float(price_formula_value)
    print(float(precioads))
```

553686.6759734167
622897.5104700937
650581.8442687645
678266.1780674353
681000.99
682000.992

Al solicitar el menor si lo hace
553686.6759734167

Espero de su gran colaboracion --Gracias de ante manos

Answer (score 0):

El problema con tu código es que solo evalua el primer valor, ya que no recorre el array de datos, y te da el valor correcto para el menor, solo por la casualidad de que está en la primera posición.
Te falta agregar un for.

```
lista = [ 553686.6759734167, 622897.5104700937, 650581.8442687645, 678266.1780674353, 681000.99, 682000.992 ]

precioads = lista[ 0 ]
for i in range( len( lista ) -1 ):
    if(  lista[ i ] < lista[ i + 1 ] ):
        precioads = lista[ i + 1 ]

print( precioads )
```

Primero asignas a **presioads** el valor que está en la primer posición del array.
luego, en el for, vas comparando el valor de cada posición, con la siguiente, en caso de ser menor (en este ejemplo, pero puedes cambiarla para obtener el resultado contrario), cambias el valor de **presioads**, por el de la posición siguiente.
Terminado el ciclo, solo te resta imprimir el resultado.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

estas tratando de comparar un valor booleano, mi consejo, según imagino lo que desea hacer en la condición debería cambia los paréntesis así,

```
if (precioads is None) or  (float(x['price_formula_value']) > float(precioads):
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias!